# c++ how to create a pointer that will last even when object is overwritten?

Tags: c++, object, pointers, smart-pointers

I am creating a `std::map` of type `<int, Foo*>`. I am populating this map in a for loop with the `emplace` function. In this loop I am creating a Foo object `Foo f = Foo()` with every loop iteration and inserting this to map like so:

```
std::map<int, Foo*> mymap;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 4; i ++)
{
    Foo f = Foo();
    mymap.emplace(i, &f);
    mymap[i]->a.pushback(pow(i,2));
}
```

where `a` is a `vector<int>` in class `Foo`
The problem is very clear. I am inserting a reference to `f` in `mymap` while on the next iteration I am recreating `f`, making the previous pointer to `f` obsolete. how can I resolve this while still keeping a pointer to `f` in `mymap` rather than storing a copy of `f`? are smart pointer a solution? (i never used them before).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your intention right. The way you do it now, `f` is invalid at the end of the loop, so your pointers are pointing to invalid memory. Try `Foo *f = new Foo;` instead, this way your map is storing pointers to `Foo` objects on the heap (that are valid until you `delete` them). Also, I'm not sure if `i^2` is intentional, that's bitwise XOR and not squaring.

Comment: "making the previous pointer to f obsolete" It is not about obsolete data, is about referencing a non loner existing object! You create a pointer from an object on the stack. After you leave your loop body, the object is not lnger there and the pointer points still to the dead thing. That is undefined behavior

Comment: @Klaus that is right. it's exactly what I wanted to solve. I found that the previous pointers were all pointing to the most recently created `f` while the loop is still iterating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably simply want:

```cpp
std::map<int, Foo> mymap;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 4; i ++)
{
    //mymap.emplace(i, Foo()); // operator[] would do similar anyway
    mymap[i].a.pushback(pow(i, 2));
}
```

or, if really you want pointer semantic

```cpp
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<Foo>> mymap;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 4; i ++)
{
    mymap.emplace(i, std::make_unique<Foo>());
    mymap[i]->a.pushback(pow(i,2));
}
```

And if you really want raw owning pointer:

```cpp
std::map<int, Foo*> mymap;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 4; i ++)
{
    mymap.emplace(i, new Foo()); // calling delete later is required to avoid leak
    mymap[i]->a.pushback(pow(i,2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I read that ideally, you should put a pointer to an object in a map rather than the object itself. That is why I did not use your first approach. which approach would you use from your 3?

Comment: I would default to put Object in the class. But for example you can't If `Foo` is polymorphic, so using smart pointer then.

Answer (score 4):

Use `new`.

```
mymap.emplace(i, new Foo());
```

See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) for more information about the `new`-oeprator.

Comment: so is `new Foo()` a pointer to an object or an object itself?

Comment: `new Foo()` will allocate space on the heap, call the `Foo::Foo` constructor on it, and return the address to you. So it is a pointer to a Foo object. In modern C++ it is advised to use `std::shared_ptr` and/or `std::unique_ptr` to automatically handle allocation and freeing for you.

Comment: @Botje I would be happy to accept your answer with std::unique_ptr on the above example if it is the correct way of doing it as a modern approach.

Comment: No, @churill's answer is also correct. Read the documentation for the shared_ptr and unique_ptr and determine which of the two ownership models fits your intention.